# Join two table and reads two record from second table

Tags: mysql, sql

I wanna join two table, reads one record from first table and two record from second table. The first table has some field that I want to select all. The second table has been connected to first table with foreign key.

**First table:**

```
+----+-------------+
| id | some_fields |
+----+-------------+
| 23 |    S.T      |
+----+-------------+
| 24 |    S.T      |
+----+-------------+
| 25 |    S.T      |
+----+-------------+
```

**Second table**

```
+----+----------+------------+
| fid| meta_key | meta_value |
+----+----------+------------+
| 24 |   meta_1 |   m_1      |
+----+----------+------------+
| 24 |   meta_2 |   m_2      |
+----+----------+------------+
| 25 |   meta_2 |   m_3      |
+----+----------+------------+
```

**Out-pot that I want:**

```
+----+-------------+--------+-------+
| id | some_fields | meta_1 | meta_2|
+----+-------------+--------+-------+
| 24 |     S.T     |   m_1  |  m_2  |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+
| 25 |     S.T     |   null |  m_3  |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+
```

I know this query is wrong:

```
 SELECT *
    FROM posts
    INNER JOIN postmeta ON ( posts.id = postmeta.fid )
    WHERE 1 =1
    AND (
    postmeta.meta_key = 'meta_1'
    OR postmeta.meta_key = 'meta_2'
    )
    AND posts.post_type = 'ignition_product'
    AND (
    posts.post_status = 'publish'
    OR posts.post_status = 'private'
    )
    GROUP BY posts.ID
    ORDER BY postmeta.meta_value +0 DESC
    LIMIT 0 , 7
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use multiple joins to `postmeta` table:

```
SELECT posts.id, posts.some_fields, meta1.meta_value as meta_1, meta2.meta_value as meta_2
FROM posts
    LEFT JOIN postmeta meta1 ON posts.id = meta1.fid AND meta_key = 'meta1'
    LEFT JOIN postmeta meta2 ON posts.id = meta2.fid AND meta_key = 'meta2'
WHERE meta1.fid IS NOT NULL OR meta2.fid IS NOT NULL
```

First `JOIN` will be used to populate the data for column `meta_1`, and the second join - populate column `meta_2`.

The query above is valid if you have only 2 types of meta. If you have more or the number is dynamic, different approach is required.

Answer (score 3):

Use a pivot query:

```
SELECT t1.id,
       t1.some_fields,
       t2.meta_1,
       t2.meta_2      
FROM posts t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT fid,
           MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'meta_1' THEN meta_value END) AS meta_1,
           MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'meta_2' THEN meta_value END) AS meta_2
    FROM postmeta
    GROUP BY fid
) t2
    ON t1.id = t2.fid
```